# Outlook Addin window.open

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I´m new to the addins, just want to perform a simple task as creating a button with a link in the taskbar that opens a browser and that´s it.

So far created the project based on ms tutorial and everything is working great (with fixed certificate problems).

To my understand this should be as easy as to create a button with an ExecuteFuncion actions mapping to a javascript function with a window.open
e.g.

```
function windowOpen(event)
{
    window.open("https://www.microsoft.com");
    event.completed();
}
```

Thanks for the help,

Regards,

André

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, Outlook does not support window.open *directly* inside of Add-ins. To open a window in an Outlook Add-in you can use the displayDialogAsync API (documentation [here](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync).)  We recommend [this guide](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) to understand end-to-end usage of displaying a dialog in an Add-in.

Comment: Than you should have accepted the answer, to help others who read this in future