# Outlook web addin (for Android) view/download docx/pdf

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to view/download a PDF/Docx file on click of anchor tag.

The link is like below

`<a href="http://iiswc.org/iiswc2012/sample.doc" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" data-auth="NotApplicable"><span style="font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont; color: rgb(25, 118, 210); background: white;">SampleDOC</span></a>`

The above link works fine with iPAD/iPhone/MAC/Windows but not in Android Outlook wed add-in.

**In Android Outlook web add-in the txt file download works fine via link.**

**Is there any other way to implement links** other than using anchor tags ?

As per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016470/outlook-addin-window-open), window.open is not supported in Outlook web add-in.

Any help is appreciated.

@microsoft team: I've uploaded below GIF which shows what happens when a link is clicked.
[image: Outlook_plugin_issue_GIF]

Please let me know if you are in need of more information

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this snippet `<a href="http://iiswc.org/iiswc2012/sample.doc" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" data-auth="NotApplicable"><span style="font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif, serif, EmojiFont; color: rgb(25, 118, 210); background: white;">SampleDOC</span></a>`, on-click you must be redirected to browser and browser will give the option to download the file. Unlike iOS, Android itself does not support rendering .doc or .ppt files.
You must be seeing the same behavior if you check the email with the same link.

Comment: when a link is in mail body the download works fine in Android. The same functionality should work fine even for links with in add-in right? Also, if Android doesn't have this feature then even IOS shouldn't have it because this leads to inconsistent behaviour

Comment: Yes, the download should work with add-ins as well. And it does work. If you are seeing the issue that download doesn't work, please attach a video of same. SO we can learn better about the issue and help you resolve it.

Comment: Please look at updated question for video on issue that I'm facing.